# Differentiability linear function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The question may seems idiot, but I prefer to ask it rather than let some doubt resist. So, we consider $f \in \mathcal{L}(E \times F, G)$ and we want to show that $f$ is differentiable in each point $(a \; b) \in E \times F$ (and calculate $Df_{(a \, b)}$).

The first question is : 
a) Write $f(a+h,b+k)$ according to $f(a,b)$, $f(a,k)$, $f(h,b)$ and $f(h,k)$. But this is the problem. In fact, I've said that :

$f(a+h,b+k) = f((a,b)+(h,k)) = f((a,b)) + f((h,k))$ as $f$ is linear.

So, we have as well :
$f(a+h,b+k) = f((a,k)+(h,b)) = f((a,k)) + f((h,b))$.

And so, if we want to answer the question, this is what I've found :
$f(a+h,b+k) = \frac{1}{2}(f((a,b)) + f((h,k)) + f((a,k)) + f((h,b)))$

But I don't figure out why we should do that to answer the show that $f$ is differentiable. Actually, let $(a \; b) \in E \times F$. Then, let $(h \; k) \in E \times F$, we have :

$f((a,b)+(h,k)) - f((a,b)) = f(a+h, b+k) - f(a,b) = f(a,b)+f(h,k)-f(a,b) = f(h,k)$. So :

$f((a,b)+(h,k)) - f((a,b)) - f(h,k) = f((a,b)+(h,k)-(a,b)-(h,k)) = 0_G$, and then : $\lim\limits_{\substack{(h \; k) \rightarrow (0 \; 0) \\ (h \; k) \neq (0 \; 0)}} \frac{||f((a,b)+(h,k)) - f((a,b)) - f(h,k)||}{||(h,k)||} = 0$, and we have finally :

$Df_{(a \; b)} : E \times F \rightarrow G$ defined by $Df_{(a \; b)}(h,k) = f(h,k)$.

I've the feeling that it's not this at all, because if it would do, what's the point of the first question ?

But I don't figure out why could been wrong, and it's my first step on differentiable functions, so I'm not sure at all of what I'm writting down...

Comment: What are $E,F,G$? A linear function on a normed space is differentiable if and only if it is continuous. On a finite dimensional space for example, every linear function is continuous. The same logic applies to multi linear functions.

Comment: Sorry, $E$, $F$, $G$, are a normed vector space.

Comment: are $E$ and $F$ finite dimensional? If they aren't, then there exist non continuous linear functions. In particular they are not differentiable.

Comment: I too ask what is the point of your first question. Writing $f(a+h, b+k)$ in terms of $f(a,b), f(h,k)$ has a purpose. But there is no useful reason to write it in terms of $f(a,k), f(b,h)$. So who came up with this question? Your derivative is correct (if somewhat painfully derived). The derivative of a linear map is itself. This is analogous to the one-dimensional fact that the derivative of $Ax = A$, except it is necessary to think of the derivative as a linear mapping, which makes it $Ax$ again.